# Preferred way to set frame at run time for different orientation

Tags: ios, frame, screen-orientation, uiinterfaceorientation, orientation-changes

I have two different UI specs for my iOS app.

I'm facing issues in orientation change(Upsidedown not supporting) for following scenario.
*FYI :I'm using using `self.view.frame.size.width` to set width for UI and to identify orientation change i'm using `UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification`*
1.Change orientation to landscape
2.change to orientation upsidedown (not settign any frame)
3.change orientation to portrait directly (setting frame for portrait mode)

On following these steps my UI frame is getting misplaced.
I'm getting width as 568 for portrait mode.

Please suggest me a better way to fix this problem.

Answer (score 1):

It is not good practice to change the `self.view` frame when rotating because its `bound` are handled by the `UIViewController` rotation logic.

You can use the `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` and `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:` delegate methods for manual rotation.

Comment: I have already tried to implement this,but it takes some time to change frames as i'm doing many other calculation functionality before changing frame so user can see the frames moving.In willRotateToInterFaceorientaion the frames are comming wrong.But thanks for the Suggestion.

Comment: Try animating the `frame` with Animation using the duration argument.

Answer (score 1):

you are listing to your device orientation changes and you need to allow UI rotation and listen to it with

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    //update your view's subviews
}
```

note that UIDeviceOrientation is different from UIInterfaceOrientation

to allow interface rotation add this to the view controller and make sure that in the project plist you are supporting the landscape  and portrait in the 'Supported interface orientations' key [image]

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
}
```